# What’s the meaning of “General variable binding error” in SNMP4J?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I use gettable to query some data successfully in one machine，but when I use the same command to query the other machine,it returns “General variable binding error”.How to fix it ? I can query the data in command line using Net-SNMP in the other machine.

Answer (score 1):

That error message is defined in `SnmpConstants.java` as part of `SNMP_ERROR_MESSAGES`,

https://github.com/kaazing/snmp4j/blob/60518cb185e7738f94a9c754e85fa220afeffe6d/src/org/snmp4j/mp/SnmpConstants.java

You can see the error message is being used only in `PDU.java`,

https://github.com/kaazing/snmp4j/blob/60518cb185e7738f94a9c754e85fa220afeffe6d/src/org/snmp4j/PDU.java

and is only used when the SNMP response message has an error status of `5`, aka `GenErr`.

That's unfortunately an ambiguous error reported by SNMP agents when they hit an exception that cannot be categorized to other error status.

So in your case,

1. try to use SNMP v2 to perform the queries and it usually gives a better error status code (v2 introduced more codes).
2. accept the fact that `GenErr` can happen and handle it (or ignore it).

Since it is an agent side behavior to return `GenErr`, you have no other option on the manager side.

Comment: I use the same command and then can query the correct result in the other machine.It seems that the reason is the machine.But on the other hand, Net-SNMP can also return the correct result in this machine.

Comment: @flower You can capture network packets to compare if you like. But such agent side errors can present miserable results (especially intermittent errors), but only the agent developers/vendors know how and why.